# Error during run npm install from pom.xml

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm, npm-install

I created java project , in the pom.xml I added section to run npm install

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <!--node modules are in the project. no need for npm install-->
            <execution>
                <id>npm install my</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>                         
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/../</workingDirectory>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

and I created also package.json in the root folder.
    The dependencies are from internal nexus and not public nexus

```
"dependencies": {
 "@test/my": "1.0.13"


        },
```

When I run mvn on the java module I got error

Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '

I thought that this error is related that it didn't find the .npmrc .
I tried to add it in different level
How I define in the pom.xml where the .npmrc is needed ? 
why does the npm doesn't look for the .npmrc ?

Comment: Every times I've seen this kind of error (unepextec token < in JSON...) on my build, it was du to wrong node / npm version

Comment: so why do I need to do ? Can I add something to the pom.xml ?

Comment: You have to figure out which version is needed to build your app. You can compare the actual version you use to compile your js app without maven to the one used by maven by using the exec maven with the `--version` parameter on npm and node.

Comment: Where I need to add the npm version in the pom.xml ?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to do this from the pom. I use nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage my node / npm versions